# Spring Azure AD Authentication

Tags: java, spring, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to implement Authentication with Spring Security via Azure AD to my Spring Boot Application. The Azure AD Portal is not availible to me and managed by others.

How can I perform an easy Authentication using the Microsoft login of the company to verify that the user exists in the Azure? I just need to know in the application if the user was able to perform the login.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> i'm trying to implement Authentication with Spring Security via Azure
> AD to my Spring Boot Application. The Azure AD Portal is not available
> to me and managed by others

**AFAIK**, ***Without having Azure portal its not possible to use authentication with Azure AD for your application. It requires app registration details such as client id, Tenant Id, redirect uri etc.***

*We can not able to do such operation if are not having account on Azure . And Azure Active directory has a high level security so that you can not get to know whether this user is from Azure.*

*For more information please refer the below links:-*

- **Dev Azure Blog**|[***Using Spring Security with Azure Active Directory***](https://dev.to/azure/using-spring-security-with-azure-active-directory-mga)
- **MICROSOFT DOCUMENT**| [***Secure a Java web app using the Spring Boot Starter for Azure Active Directory***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory)